# Profinite free modules and intersections

Tags: continuity, free-modules, profinite-groups

This is the part (c) in Exercise 5.2.4 of Luis Ribes' and Pavel Zalesskii's book *Profinite Groups*.

> Let $\Lambda$ be a profinite ring, $(X, *)$ be a pointed profinite
>   space and $(Y_i,*)$ be a family indexed by $i \in I$ of pointed closed
>   subsets of $(X,*)$. Set $Y = \bigcap_{i \in I} Y_i$. Prove that, after
>   identifying the free profinite $\Lambda$-modules below with their respective
>   images in $[[\Lambda(X,*)]]$, we have the identity: $$[[\Lambda(Y,*)]]
>  = \bigcap_{i \in I} [[\Lambda(Y_i,*)]]\,.$$

I've managed to prove this result assuming that the family $Y_i$ is filtered from below, i.e., for any pair $Y_i$ and $Y_k$ there exists a $Y_j$ satisfyng $Y_j \subseteq Y_i\cap Y_k$. This condition implies that the intersection commutes with continuous functions by a compactness argument. Is this exercise still true without the filtration hypothesis? I fail to see how I may go around proving this, but I haven't been able to provide a counter-example either.

**EDIT** My proof for the filtered case is also wrong. So far, all I know is that the free profinite $\Lambda$-module functor is exact in the category of pointed topological spaces.

Comment: One can assume that $\{Y_i\}$ is filtered from below by exchanging it with the family of all it's finite intersections?

Comment: This seems to be fully solved in Lemma 2.4.8 of Luis Ribes' *Profinite Graphs and Groups*